# Is it possible to make a request to an account other than "Friendbot" to receive Lumens?

Tags: assets, javascript-sdk, token, wallets, stellar-sdk

From the documentation you can make a request using Javascript to the "Friendbot" to receive test Lumens for an account:

```
// The SDK does not have tools for creating test accounts, so you'll have to
// make your own HTTP request.
var request = require('request');
request.get({
  url: 'https://friendbot.stellar.org',
  qs: { addr: pair.publicKey() },
  json: true
}, function(error, response, body) {
  if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
    console.error('ERROR!', error || body);
  }
  else {
    console.log('SUCCESS! You have a new account :)\n', body);
  }
});
```

Is it possible to do something similar to this but that would send a request to an account where I have a large amount of XLM (my "reserve" account).

For context of this question: I would like to try to implement some method that upon creation of stellar wallets in my Dapp for users there would be a request sent so that some from my reserve of XLM would be sent to their account so they could cover base and minimum fees and pay to send tokens I would give them.

Thanks for any help, I'm just learning how to work with stellar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an operation called createAccount, and it's used to activate accounts with a starting balance. In fact all friendbot does is exactly what you are saying (it has a base account with a large balance and it does createAccount with 10000 lumens).

https://stellar.github.io/js-stellar-sdk/Operation.html#.createAccount

Here's some sample code:

```
const transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(sourceAccount)
  .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.createAccount({
    destination: destinationId,
    startingBalance: "10"
   }))
   .build();

transaction.sign(sourceKeys);
return server.submitTransaction(transaction);
```

Comment: Thanks, so if I was to create accounts for an application I could use code like that to crate them and send a starting balance of XLM from the `sourceAccount`?
How would I get a `destinationId` value though if the account was not yet created?

Comment: That's correct. You can generate a keypair (public/private key) without actually "creating it" on the stellar network by activating it with lumens. See https://stellar.github.io/js-stellar-sdk/Keypair.html#.random